# How to import buckets of Google cloud storage in firebase automatically?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have various buckets in google cloud storage which is being created from my backend. I want to import these buckets to firebase. In firebase there is a option to import the google cloud buckets to firebase, but I want to automate these tasks because any number of buckets can be created in my app and I cannot go to firebase always and import the buckets to it. how to do this?

Comment: I had always assumed that firebase storage and GCP cloud storage were the same animals ... meaning that an object in GCS was the same object in firebase storage.

Comment: @Kolban The buckets are the same, but Firebase keeps its own list of buckets for the project.

Comment: What is the process you are mentioning to import the buckets from GCP to Firebase? I ask because I would simply move the bucket with an SDK as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#apis)

Comment: @rsalinas you can check this https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/multiplying-power-firebase-storage.html link out to import manually.

Comment: For what I can see in the guide, the UI is only doing a move as if you did it with the SDK, so I would say that you can take this approach too and just move your buckets

Comment: Can you share SDK link to move bucket to firebase? @rsalinas

Comment: You can find the document [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#apis)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is REST API method.

```
POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v1beta/{bucket=projects/*/buckets/*}:addFirebase
```

Links a Google Cloud Storage bucket to a Firebase project.

source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/storage/rest/v1beta/projects.buckets/addFirebase

Comment: can you please explain how to do this in c#. I want to do it in a unity project

Comment: This is more of a serverside thing. You have to generate credentials too so it's quite complicated. How will you store the credentials in a clientside Unity project?